# Prove that the infimum exists?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I want to prove that there exist a unique element  $P_{k_0}(v)$ in $U_{k_0}$ such that
$$\|v-P_{k_0}(v)\|_2=\inf\limits_{x\in U_{k_0}}\| v-x\|_2$$
($U_{k_0}=\mathrm{span} (\varepsilon_0,\dots,\varepsilon_{k_0},\varepsilon_{N-k_0},\dots,\varepsilon_{N-1})$)
$U_{k_0} \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$

$x$ in $U_{k_0}$ :

$\| v-x\|_2^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}|\hat{v}_n-\hat{x}_n|^2 $
($\hat{x}_n$and $\hat{v}_n$ belong to fourier basis)

- I've tried to use Weierstrass' theorem and Pythagorean theorem but couldn't find any results.

thank you .

Comment: I think you are looking for the Hilbert projection theorem, a well known result.

Comment: may you please clarify ?

Comment: Actually ...if I want to use the Hilbert projection theorem proof , $U_k_0$ has to be closed and convexe ...